# "A friend of Susan" vs. "a friend of Susan's"

Tags: grammaticality, double-possessive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of)

I'm currently having hot debates with a friend of mine about which one is more natural and more grammatically correct:

> - A friend of Susan
> - A friend of Susan's

I vote for the first, but I don't have anything to prove I'm right.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate; the other question is about pronoun usage, this is about whether you add apostrophe-s to a name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*A friend of Susan’s* is a double genitive, which has been a feature of English grammar for centuries, and it is the normal alternative to *one of Susan’s friends*. Just as most people would say *a friend of mine*, rather than *a friend of me*, so *a friend of Susan’s*, rather than *a friend of Susan*, would be the natural choice in most contexts.

Comment: So it's not about some grammar rules but about, uhm, accents?

Comment: No, it's nothing whatever to do with accents. English grammar accommodates the double genitive without difficulty, and it is not at all unusual.