# A friend of John's / John's friend

Tags: grammaticality, noun-phrases, saxon-genitive, double-possessive

**The question:**

Suppose John is my friend, and I am introducing myself to his brother, should I say

> "I am a friend of John's"

or

> "I am John's friend"

??

I would use the former, but some think the latter is also correct. If both are acceptable, what are the differences? If we can already say *John's friend*, why do we need constructions like *a friend of John's* in English?

---

<sup>**Note:**</sup>

<sup>There are lots of question on this site asking about [*a friend of John* versus *a friend of John's
*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90063/a-friend-of-susan-vs-a-friend-of-susans) and so forth. This however, is not one of those questions!</sup>

Comment: Both are fine. The "John's friend" version is less formal.

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you for your comment! By "less formal", do you mean "less common"?

Comment: He doesn't necessarily mean less common. What @Lawrence means is that is has less formality. Read about things being formal or informal (even just the definitions) and you will likely understand what he meant.

Comment: @Kace36 Thanks; yes, I was referring to the register.

Comment: @WWang Compare: "Good evening, welcome to our fine establishment." *vs* "Yo! What's up?"

Comment: For all practical purposes, they’re interchangeable.  However, some might interpret “I am John’s friend” to mean “I am John’s *only* friend”.  By contrast, “I am a friend of John’s” more clearly communicates “I am *one of* John’s friend ***s***”.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks. I didn't know they are that different.

Comment: @WWang I've exaggerated the difference in my examples for effect. Your examples are fairly close, but since you asked for differences in your question, I mentioned one. :)

Comment: Yes, please don't take them to mean something so drastically different. They are quite similar. It's just that one is very slightly less formal. His comparison example was quite good but also exaggerated for effect ;)

Comment: @Lawrence I think there's a bit more going on (see my answer below for why).

Comment: @Kace36 There's a bit more than this going on, I think (see below). It's not really about formality at all.

Comment: So so many possible duplicates, one of which might be: of [Why is it usually "friend of his", but no possessive apostrophe with "friend of Peter"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of)

Comment: @Mitch Well, that one's not a dupe of this!! It's a completely different question. This question isn't asking about *a friend of John* versus *a friend of John's*!!! Whatchou talkin about Lewis?

Comment: @Araucaria just search for 'friend of' here. YOu'll get,
 among many many others,
 [a-friend-of-susan-vs-a-friend-of-susans](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90063/a-friend-of-susan-vs-a-friend-of-susans) which was marked as a duplicate of the 'friend of Peter' question. How much more duplicate can you get without it being a duplicate? Your answer is fine but, administratively, should be made on one of the other duplicates.

Comment: @Mitch If you look at all the 'related questions' on the right, you'll see that they're all about *X of Y* versus *X of Y's*. They aren't about *X of Y's* versus *Y's X* - and why we need both constructions.

Comment: The answer to all "why does this happen in English" questions is : _Because it's English_.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer**

You could say either. However, it would perhaps be more natural to say *a friend of John's*, as the Original Poster suggests. The reason for this is that the speaker will probably want to mark the noun phrase as indefinite.

---

**Full answer**

Noun phrases in English come in two parts. For example, in the noun phrase *a huge elephant,* the first part is the word *a*, the second  the chunk *huge elephant*. We have a special name for the job that the word *a* is doing in the phrase. We call it the Determiner. We can use different types of words to do that job. We can use words like *the, that, this, some, any*, called *determinatives*, or we can use a genitive noun phrase like *the dog's* or *Bill's* or *my* or *your* or *his*.

However, it is a rule of English that we can only use  one such item in Determiner function. For this reason the following noun phrases are badly formed:

- *a the dog (ungrammatical)
- *some John's elephants (ungrammatical)
- *any these things (ungrammatical)

Now, one of the jobs that Determiners can do in noun phrases is to mark them as either *definite*—meaning that the speaker is indicating the listener will identify which thing(s) the speaker is talking about—or *indefinite*—in which case the listener will not already know the identity of the things being discussed. We can see this contrast in the following pair of examples:

- A man  spoke to me.
- The man spoke to me.

In the first example, the listener does not know which man is being talked about; we don't know the identity of the man in question. In the second, the listener is expected to understand which man is being referred to. The speaker has probably already mentioned the man in their previous discourse.

Usually when we think about noun phrases being marked as definite or indefinite we automatically think about the words *a* and *the*. But in fact many other words in  Determiner function can do this as well. So, for example the words *some* and *any* mark noun phrases as indefinite, and the words *this* and *that* mark phrases as definite. In the string *Some idiot nicked my chocolate cake*, the listener will not know the identity of the idiot. In contrast, in *That idiot nicked my chocolate cake,* the identity of the miscreant will be clear to the listener.

In English, genitive noun phrases used as Determiners tend to give the larger noun phrase a definite flavour. So if you are visiting a business where one of John's friends works and they are going to meet you to show you round, they may well walk up to you and say *Hi, I'm John's friend,* because they will expect you to understand *which* friend of John's they are referring to (it's the one who you're expecting to meet!).

In some other languages, such as Italian, possessive words such as *my* or *your* don't work in the same way as they do in English. They are Modifiers within the noun phrase; they're not Determiners. For this reason in Italian you can say things like:

- la mia amica — *the my friend*
- una mia amica — *a my friend*

Notice that in English we cannot do this. The reason is, of course, that we can have only one item in the Determiner function, and the English versions of these phrases have two (*the my* /*a my*), rendering them ungrammatical.

As we have seen, because genitive noun phrases like *John's* or *my* tend to give noun phrases a definite flavour, we don't need any other structure to give the same kind of meaning as *the John's friend*. We can simply say *John's friend* instead. However, there's a problem if we want to say something like *a John's friend*, where we are implying that this denotes one of several or many of his friends, and we are implying that which specific one is not known to the listener. The restriction on more than one item in Determiner function makes it impossible to have both *John's* and *a* in that slot. As with other such situations when we might wish to use two Determiners together in one noun phrase, we get round this by using an *of*-preposition phrase to modify the Head noun. The second Determiner will now appear within a smaller noun phrase inside the preposition phrase. So instead of:

- *a John's friend (ungrammatical)

we get:

- a friend of John's

Some people interpret the structure of this as:

- a friend of John's <s>friends</s>

where the second *friends* has been deleted and the word *John's* occurs on its own as a fused Determiner-Head noun phrase. Of course, the *of* here would signify the "member of a set" relationship, as in *he is one of us* or *one of them* and so forth.

---

**The Original Poster's question**

1. I'm John's friend.
2. I'm a friend of John's.

Speakers will opt for (1) when *John's friend* is meant to denote a specific friend that is already salient to the listener. Example (2) is likely to be used when the speaker wants to make the noun phrase indefinite so that it has the same meaning as *a John's friend* would have if such noun phrases were allowable in English.

Assuming that the speaker isn't known of in any way by the listener, a majority of speakers would use the second example here. The first *could* give the impression that either John only has one friend, or that the listener should in some way be expecting a specific friend of John's.

---

<sup>**Grammar note**</sup>

<sup>Genitive noun phrases used as Determiners tend to give the larger noun phrase a definite flavour when they are used with the verb *BE* in its specifying sense (i.e., when it denotes the identity of something). When the verb *BE* is used in its ascriptive sense (to denote a quality of the Subject), this no longer applies. So if a speaker wants to imply that they have a friendly disposition towards John, as opposed to being his enemy, then within the phrase *I am John's friend*, the NP *John's friend* will not be interpreted as definite.</sup>

Comment: If you say *"I am John's brother,"* does it mean that John only has one brother? Otherwise would you say *"I am a brother of John's"* or *"I am one of John's brothers"*? No, it doesn't, and you wouldn't. In some dialects (U.S. Northeast, for example), *friend* works like *brother*.

Comment: @PeterShor No, it doesn't. Note that I put *could* in italics, used *tend to* and *majority* etc, etc. I don't agree  at all that *friend* works like *brother* though. There are many, many reasons why. One of these is that, as your experience will no doubt tell you, we rarely say "I am one of John's brothers" as an intoduction, and extremely, extremely rarely say "I am a brother of John's" whereas we are extremely likely to say "I'm a friend of John's". As detailed in ....

Comment: @PeterShor ... [Payne 2009, *The Oblique Genitive in English*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.458.5946&rep=rep1&type=pdf), although there are some similarities between personal relation oblique genitives and kinship genitives they do not pattern in the same way. So, if you look at that research, you'll see that the findings show that personal relation obliques are almost seven times more common that kinship obliques. You'll also see that there are many trends and probabilities exhibited, but that these are just those ...

Comment: I live in the U.S. Northeast, and I was quite confused when I first moved here until I realized that *friend* worked more like *brother* than it did in California.

Comment: @PeterShor Ok, but do you really mean that, or do you mean that *brother* worked more like *friend*? (I'd believe both but am just checking)

Comment: I mean *friend* works like *brother*. People here sometimes say *my friend* when in any place that spoke standard English, they'd say *one of my friends*. If you're not used to it, it can be quite disconcerting. You think "by *friend*, do they mean *partner*"? (No, they don't.)

Comment: Seriously?  Some people interpret “a friend of John’s” to mean “a friend of John’s friends” (rather than “*one* of John’s friends”)?

Comment: @Scott Yes, where the *of* signifies a member of a set (or simply *one of*). So it means *a friend from the set of John's friends*.

Comment: Definite does not mean "that the listener can identify which thing(s) the speaker is talking about", but actually "that the speaker assumes the listener can identify which thing(s) he's talking about."

Answer (score -3):

"I am a friend of John's" means John's have many friends and you're one of them. but if you say  "I am John's friend", it sounds you're a close friend to John. in my opinion, you should use  "I am John's friend" to introduce yourself to others. thank you :)

"I am a friend of John's" is wrong, of course.