# "I am a big fan of you" or "I am a big fan of yours"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which one of them is correct?

"I am a big fan of you" or **"I am a big fan of yours" ?****

I think the last one, but the first one seems ok.

Comment: "I am a big fan of your work".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it usually "friend of his", but no possessive apostrophe with "friend of Peter"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of)

Comment: The second is a double genitive construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'...big fan of yours' is both the usual expression, and is the correct form as well. The former is likely incorrect.

http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=561802 (response by xhalli).

http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic14888.html

Answer (score 1):

The latter '...big fan of yours' is certainly the usual expression. But I see no reason why you shouldn't say '...fan of you' if you want to. It is not ungrammatical.

Comment: See [also](http://cheezburger.com/3229606656)....

Comment: @Elliot: Lol - you can now consider me [a big fan of yourn](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22a+big+fan+of+yourn%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)