# Does "In the event of ..." take the genitive case?

Tags: grammar, possessives, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case

Is insisting on a genitive pronoun after "In the event of ..." pedantry or correct?

For example: "In the event of ..."

- his/him winning the election
- my/me dying
- our/us leaving

For those who advocate the genitive, would you also write "In the event of Peter's leaving"?

Comment: For more support and discussion of all this, do please see the references I provide [below in a comment to the Accepted answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163036/does-in-the-event-of-take-the-genitive-case#comment340455_163057).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Insisting* on a genitive pronoun *(my, his) + **noun*** in such constructions would be sheer pedantry, but in practice we do overwhelmingly prefer it to the simple pronoun *(me, him) + **verb***...

[image]

It's worth homing in on that "flatline" above...

[image]

What those charts show is that although there's still a marked preference for the genitive, the usage is in fact declining, whereas the simple pronoun + verb form has *gained* traction.

Also note that if a "standard" noun can follow the genitive *([in the event of his **death**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22engineered%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20his%20death%22&tbm=bks))* that's what we prefer. But we'd still rather stick to the genitive even with a gerund *([in the event of **his dying**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22engineered%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20his%20dying%22&tbm=bks))*. Relatively speaking, the pronoun + verb form *([in the event of **him dying**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22engineered%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20him%20dying%22&tbm=bks))* isn't a popular choice.

---

Having said all that, the preference for a *genitive/possessive + [gerund] noun* form only really applies with pronouns. Consider [this earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of), and these results from Google Books...

> *in the event of the king being* [(3,010 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%20being%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    *in the event of the king's being* [(7 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%20being%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%27s%20being%22&tbm=bks)
>    *in the event of the king dying* [(1,520 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%20being%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%20dying%22&tbm=bks)
>    *in the event of the king's dying* [(114 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%20being%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%27s%20dying%22&tbm=bks)

Although as pointed out, with [21,700 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%20being%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22in%20the%20event%20of%20the%20king%27s%20death%22&tbm=bks), *in the event of the king's death* is far more common than either of those last two.

---

TL;DR: The genitive form is still far more common *with pronouns* - but it's becoming less so, and grammatically speaking there's nothing wrong with the *[pro]noun + verb* alternative. Kudos to @tchrist's comment below for guiding me to [this from CGEL](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2637)..

> *Modern usage manuals generally **do not condemn non-genitives altogether** (as Fowler did in early work), though they vary in their tolerance of them, the more conservative ones advocating a genitive except where it sounds awkward, stilted, or pedantic [...]*

Comment: Maybe it’s just me, but I try to avoid talking about people’s genitives in English. I prefer to call the *my,thy,his,her,its,our,your,their* set **possessive determiners**, and reserve to the *mine,thine,his,hers,its,ours,yours,theirs* set the term **possessive pronouns**.  Now technically these are all personal not impersonal forms, since in the impersonal forms, there is never a difference in the determiner usage versus the pronominal one: *one’s, anybody’s, someone’s*. So pronominally: “Whose hat is that?  It’s mine. It’s yours.” versus “It’s anybody’s. It’s somebody else’s.”

Comment: You might want to read through [this short blogue posting](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2641), particularly [its antecedent, “Possessive with gerund: Tragic loss or good riddance?”](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2637) and the paper it cites, [“Pronominal Determiners in Gerundive Nominalization: A ‘Case’ Study”](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/Heyvaert2005.pdf) by Liesbet Heyvaert et al. in *English Studies* 86(1): 71–88, 2005.

Comment: @tchrist Yes: if you call 's a "genitive" in English, then we really need a different term to refer to the genitive in languages that actually have an overt Case system...!

Comment: @Neil, tchrist: All true, but the specific context being queried is more about whether we're using the following ***-ing*** form as a "gerund noun" (with a preceding "possessive" form) or as "verb participle" (preceded by a simple noun or "object pronoun"). The one permutation we *don't* use is "[non-pro-]noun + [non-gerund] noun", so nobody ever makes plans for *in the event of the **king death***.

Answer (score -1):

I like the focus on descriptive grammar. Grammar is what grammar does, not what it should do. But "possessive descriptor"? C'mon, that's a stretch. How about plain old "possessive adjective"

E.g., ... in the event of his dying [ whose dying? HIS]

But I wouldn't soil my underwear if someone said "him dying". 
They are both acceptable to me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "possessive descriptor" is used in no answer or comment on this page but yours. Did you mean to say "possessive determiner"?