# Are there other grammatical ways to say, "I'm reading a novel of Steinbeck's"?

Tags: grammar, possessives, possessive-s-vs-of

I would like to ask why the following sentence is only possible according to grammatical rules:

> I'm reading a novel of Steinbeck's

What's wrong with "I'm reading a novel of Steinbeck" or "I'm reading Steinbeck's novel"?

Comment: or I'm reading a Steinbeck novel. Or: I'm reading a Steinbeck.

Comment: All three options are equally fine. See [Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of). What is *not* fine, however, is your usage of  the [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%B4). It's something you put atop of letters. A letter part, not a punctuation mark. Do not misuse it as an apostrophe. That's like replacing a b with a d. They might look very similar, but they don't mean remotely the same thing.

Comment: That should be "why the following sentence is the only grammatical way of expressing the thought." To which the answer is "It isn't."

Comment: Wouldn't “I am reading Steinbeck's novel” imply that he only ever wrote one?

Answer (score 3):

Usually native speakers would prefer the phrase:

> I'm reading a novel **by** Steinbeck

*by* denotes authorship, *of* and the possessive apostrophe are instead associated with ownership. Compare: "*I'm reading a book of my father*" which is ambiguous without previous or further context. (1) The book might be *about* my father; (2) he could be the *owner* of the said book, (3) he is the writer. Whereas "I'm reading a book by my father" means my father is the author of that book. In the case of "Steinbeck", the following phrases are grammatically correct:

> I'm reading a book **of** Steinbeck
>   I'm reading a book **of Steinbeck's**
>   I'm reading **Steinbeck's** novel

the problem of ambiguity is unlikely because he is such a well-known author.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of) say:

> ***Of***
>   3. **Indicating an association between two entities, typically one of
>   belonging, in which the first is the head of the phrase and the second
>   is something associated with it**:
>   *the son of a friend*
>   *the government of India*
>   *a photograph of the bride*  [WITH A POSSESSIVE]: a former colleague of John’s
>
> 3.1. **Expressing the relationship between an author, artist, or composer and their works collectively**:
>   *the plays of Shakespeare*
>   *the paintings of Rembrandt*

[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/of) says

> ***Of***
>    4. **used for saying who something belongs to**
>   *the property of the residents*
>   *They ended up living in the house of Jeanne's oldest brother.*
>
> 5.**concerning or showing someone or something**
>   *She had a photograph of him beside her bed.*
>   *It was a tale of war and bravery.*
>   *a history of Russia*
>
> 16.**used for saying who wrote a book or play, produced a work of art etc**
>   *the wonderful paintings of Picasso  the plays of Harold Pinter*

Comment: i reckon most B and A english speakers say "I'm reading a Tom Clancy novel" "I'm reading a Steinbeck novel".  It would be unusual to add the "by"

Comment: I don’t think “I’m reading a book of Steinbeck” sounds right.  I think it has to be either *a book of Steinbeck’s* or else *a book by Steinbeck* — or perhaps *a Steinbeck book*.  But I can’t quite put my finger on why.  It’s just an instinct.