# The use of "that of" and an apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe, that, double-possessive, prepositions

Here is my sentence: "Julia's experience is similar to that of Robert's."

Would it be correct to put an apostrophe ('s) after Robert?

Comment: No it wouldn't. You've already indicated "possession" with the word ***of***, and except for "quirky" usages such as [*friend of **his***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of), we don't normally expect this kind of "double genitive".

Comment: You could say *Julia's experience is similar to Robert's*

Comment: This would absolutely be correct if you wanted to say that Julia's experience is similar to the experience Robert's experience experienced.

Comment: It seems likely that a question asking essentially the same thing that this one does already exists on this site—but I sure can't find it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ["this **experience of David's** was...."](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y5hkBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT92&dq=%22experience+of+david's%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcp8zKvt_KAhVECBoKHcohC_UQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=%22experience%20of%20david's%22&f=false)

Comment: @sumelic: Sure, plus *an experience of his,* and *a friend of David's*. But you can't say they're *similar to **that of hers*** (OP's, I mean! :)

Comment: @Sven: I think this one sorta "bleeds across" to the *friend of his/him* one. It's the *pronouns* that sharpen the focus, and here it would unquestionably be *Her experience is similar to that of him*. Except we'd normally shift the possessive to the pronoun: *[hers] is similar to **his***. Whatever - I think it's potentially at least as *interesting* as the other question, and there does seem to be *some* overlap.

Comment: Related question, [Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That "friend of his"/"friend of Peter's" question definitely has some overlap with this one—and it is both well asked and well answered. Thanks for pointing it out. (I hadn't gleaned from your earlier comment that it was so similar to the present question.) Still, Maria W1234's question, besides being well titled,  has a canonical aspect in the specific case where "X's experience" is being compared not with "his experience" but with "that of Robert['s]." It seems sufficiently different to deserve in-depth answering on its own, I think, if anyone is up to the task.

Comment: I found [*As such, the reader may mistakenly equate Luke's intention to be similar to that of **John's.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22be+similar+to+that+of+John%27s%22) easily enough. And *two* instances of [*similar to that of **my wife's***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22similar+to+that+of+my+wife%27s%22). They feel "wrong", but there's obviously *something* leading people to "double up" the possessive markers - and I suspect it involves the same process here as in the *friends of **his*** context.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence should be "Julia's experience is similar to that of Robert."
If you were to say eg. "Julia's experience is similar to that of Robert's brother." then you would need the possessive apostrophe.

Comment: But there is also something to be said for the parallel presentation that the wording "Julia's experience is similar to Robert's" provides. The choice between those two options isn't one you can base on a superior claim to grammatical correctness of one or the other, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say
"Julia's experience is similar to Robert's".

If you include 'that of', no apostrophe should be used in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with the first sentence, but not the second. "The experience of Robert" is not idiomatic, so I don't think "Julia's experience is similar to that of Robert" is idiomatic either.

Comment: that's a good point.