# How to use possessive case in the following sentences?

Tags: possessives, possessive-s-vs-of, possessive-pronouns

We can say:

- the smell of it

Can we say:

- the arrival of him
- the son of me

And we can't say:

- a suggestion of Mr. Smith (should be Mr.Smith's, right?)

Can we say:

- a suggestion of Mr. Smith appointed at that time. (the modifier is long)

Comment: Just as you wouldn't say *a suggestion of **me*** (it's *a suggestion of **mine***), it would be *a suggestion of **Mr. Smith's***. Except we'd nearly always use just the Saxon genitive ***Mr. Smith's suggestion*** rather than the [double possessive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/) in that context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The answers you cite are not duplicates. Please reopen this question, which is not about the double possessive, but asks if it's possible not to use the possessive with *of*, particularly with pronouns. The answer is yes, even in the rare case of the first person pronoun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't understand why my question has the same meaning with the thing you posted. The sample I wrote down is totally different. Could you please reopen my question? Really appreciate your help

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks so much for your kind help!!! Besides, I can't understand why we can say: the smell of him. we can't say:  the arrival of hm ?

Comment: Your suggestion is ungrammatical, and not because of the possessive.  I think that's why everybody is confused. *"Mr. Smith appointed at that time will see you tomorrow."* is ungrammatical. You should revise it before it's reopened. Maybe *"A suggestion of Mr. Smith, the husband of the mayor."* Or something similar.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for your help! The meaning is: a suggestion of Mr. Smith+appointed at that time

Comment: We would probably say *"Mr. Smith who was appointed at that time"*. (Assuming you mean that somebody appointed Mr. Smith at that time.)

Comment: @PeterShor no, the meaning is a suggestion of Mr.smith's, then it was appointed at that time. "appointed at that time" is used to modify "a suggestion"

Answer (score -2):

Generally if the said noun is animated we use 's with the noun and if inanimated we use 'of' with the noun, eg, the boy's book, here the referred  noun is animated. likewise, the legs of the chair, the referred noun is inanimated.Still there are some exception to this rule, if the noun inanimated is personified the rule as stated for animated noun is to be followed, like, sun's ray

Comment: It’s [not true that we don’t use the apostrophe-s for inanimate relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/100073/2085).